# Expansion File Download feature not working

Tags: java, android

I am trying to test my app for expansion file functionality in android. But, Downloading is not working. I have used SampleDownloaderActivity.java code for showing the progress of download. 
But, no download progress is visible on the Screen. I have included required code from the documentation given on http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

I have to test app for expansion file download.

When the app launches the UI created from SampleDownloaderActivity.java is visible, tapping on Pause Download button crashes the app giving null pointer exception.

Below is the code where app is crashing

```
 mPauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mStatePaused) 
                {
                    mRemoteService.requestContinueDownload();
                }
                else 
                {
                    mRemoteService.requestPauseDownload();
                }
                setButtonPausedState(!mStatePaused);
            }
        });
     }
```

Below is the crash log I am getting :-

```
07-17 22:26:21.998: E/AndroidRuntime(19293): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-17 22:26:21.998: E/AndroidRuntime(19293):    at com.lht.egoscue.SampleDownloaderActivity$2.onClick(SampleDownloaderActivity.java:360)
07-17 22:26:21.998: E/AndroidRuntime(19293):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
07-17 22:26:21.998: E/AndroidRuntime(19293):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
07-17 22:26:21.998: E/AndroidRuntime(19293):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-17 22:26:21.998: E/AndroidRuntime(19293):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-17 22:26:21.998: E/AndroidRuntime(19293):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-17 22:26:21.998: E/AndroidRuntime(19293):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
07-17 22:26:21.998: E/AndroidRuntime(19293):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-17 22:26:21.998: E/AndroidRuntime(19293):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-17 22:26:21.998: E/AndroidRuntime(19293):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
07-17 22:26:21.998: E/AndroidRuntime(19293):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-17 22:26:21.998: E/AndroidRuntime(19293):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `mRemoteService` NULL? Try replacing your code with:

```
mPauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mRemoteService != NULL) {
                    if (mStatePaused) 
                    {
                        mRemoteService.requestContinueDownload();
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        mRemoteService.requestPauseDownload();
                    }
                    setButtonPausedState(!mStatePaused);
                }
                else { Log.wtf("SampleDownloaderActivity", "mRemoteService is NULL!!"); }
            }
        });
     }
```

---

## Pt 2:

Do you know if `onServiceConnected` is *really* being called?  To quote your doc:

> **onServiceConnected(Messenger m):**
>
> > After you instantiate the IStub in your activity, you'll receive a call to this method, which passes a
> >     Messenger object that's connected with your instance of
> >     DownloaderService. To send requests to the service, such as to pause
> >     and resume downloads, you must call
> >     DownloaderServiceMarshaller.CreateProxy() to receive the
> >     IDownloaderService interface connected to the service.

So, have you: 
1. Implemented the `IDownloaderClient` interface in your class?
2. Have you instantiated the `IStub` in your Activity?

Comment: I know I can add that check, but my question is why mRemoteService is null?

Comment: @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(Messenger m) {
        mRemoteService = DownloaderServiceMarshaller.CreateProxy(m);
        mRemoteService.onClientUpdated(mDownloaderClientStub.getMessenger());
    }

Comment: Check my updated answer, my response was slightly too long to fit into a comment.

Comment: Yes, it has been instantiated, but my activity is not responding same as the sample project provided by google. No call is coming in onServiceConnected method, I am really confused where I am doing mistake.

Comment: You should post the code where you are instantiating the `IStub`.

Comment: This line is included right above the lines, where UI of Screen is being initialized. And the stub is receiving value too. mDownloaderClientStub = DownloaderClientMarshaller.CreateStub
                (this, SampleDownloaderService.class);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33658/discussion-between-rupa-singh-and-george-mitchell)

Comment: Thanks George for all your answers, your explanations helped me in finding the solution, I got the solution, Actually the service which is being used to bind Intent is being delivered wrong through the activity, I need to correct the service only..:)

Comment: Have you tried: [developer.google.com](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html#Testing) and are you following the [rules and limitations](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html#Rules)?

Comment: @GeorgeMitchell what's the solution then? I can't have access to the chat room!

Comment: Nothing was said in the chat room haha, I was busy at work when that was posted. Look four comments above this one.

Comment: @GeorgeMitchell could you please post a more detailed answer for the solution? I don't really understand your explanation and I seem to have the same problem :(